# Show exposed filter value when returning results

Tags: views

I can't seem to figure this one out. I have a view that returns nodes with a set of taxonomy term exposed filters. What I would like to do is show the selection the user has made on the screen (e.g "Showing results for..."), preferably using a text field in the views header else through the views template files. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a bit tricky, but works:

1. Add a field `(term) Taxonomy term: Name (Name)`
   in settings check: *exclude from display*
2. Add header:  Global: Unfiltered text
   check: *Use replacement tokens from the first row* 
   set the text area with the available token: e.g *"Showing results for [name]"*

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Seems to do the trick, but when you land on the page and shows the default results (any taxonomy term) the replacement token outputs one particular taxonomy term rather than 'Any' value, would you know why?

Comment: Yes, and it's quite simple to fix it. Just go to  field `(term) Taxonomy term: Name (Name)` settings -> No results behavior and type there the default text e.g: `any`.